# Can Digital Ocean Stateless Servers (I have 4 servers running on Digital Ocean) work with the Caching Policy I implemented on Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, caching, deployment, digital-ocean

I have implemented Caching in my Spring Boot REST Application. My policy includes a time based cache eviction strategy, and an update-based cache eviction strategy. I am worried that since I employ a stateless server, if there is a method called to update certain data, and this was handled by server instance A, then the corresponding caches in server instance B, C and D, are not updated as well.

Is this an issue I would face / is there a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is the oldest problem in software development - cache invalidation when you have multiple servers

1. One way to handle it is to move your cache out of the individual servers and move them to somewhere shared like another instance that holds the cache entries that every other app refers to or something like redis [centralized cache]
2. Second way is to do a broadcast message so that each server now knows to invalidate the entry once the data has been modified or deleted - here you run the risk of the message not being processed and thus a stale entry is left in some server[s]
3. Another option is to have some sort of write ahead log [like kafka or redis streams] which is processed by each server and thus they will all process the events deterministically and have the same cache state

Lmk if you need more help - we can setup some time outside of SO